# Problem with error Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, foreach, slice

I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at Object.renderResults (searchView.js:93)
    at _callee$ (index.js:85)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:65)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:303)
    at Generator.prototype.(:8081/anonymous function) [as next] (webpack:///./node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js?:117:21)
    at step (index.js:41)
    at eval (index.js:41)
```

after searching for let's say 'pizza' in the search bar in my project, it's my github repo: https://github.com/damianjnc/finalforkify

I believe there might be an error in this part of the code:

```
export const renderResults = (recipes, page = 1, resPerPage = 10) => {
    // render results of currente page
    const start = (page - 1) * resPerPage;
    const end = page * resPerPage;

    recipes.slice(start, end).forEach(recipe => renderRecipe(recipe));

    // render pagination buttons
    renderButtons(page, recipes.length, resPerPage);
};
```

in file searchView.js:

```js
import { elements } from './base';

export const getInput = () => elements.searchInput.value;

export const clearInput = () => {
    elements.searchInput.value = '';
};

export const clearResults = () => {
    elements.searchResList.innerHTML = '';
    elements.searchResPages.innerHTML = '';
};

export const highlightSelected = id => {
    const resultsArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.results__link'));
    resultsArr.forEach(el => {
        el.classList.remove('results__link--active');
    });
    document.querySelector(`.results__link[href*="${id}"]`).classList.add('results__link--active');
};

/*
// 'Pasta with tomato and spinach'
acc: 0 / acc + cur.length = 5 / newTitle = ['Pasta']
acc: 5 / acc + cur.length = 9 / newTitle = ['Pasta', 'with']
acc: 9 / acc + cur.length = 15 / newTitle = ['Pasta', 'with', 'tomato']
acc: 15 / acc + cur.length = 18 / newTitle = ['Pasta', 'with', 'tomato']
acc: 18 / acc + cur.length = 24 / newTitle = ['Pasta', 'with', 'tomato']
*/
export const limitRecipeTitle = (title, limit = 17) => {
    const newTitle = [];
    if (title.length > limit) {
        title.split(' ').reduce((acc, cur) => {
            if (acc + cur.length <= limit) {
                newTitle.push(cur);
            }
            return acc + cur.length;
        }, 0);

        // return the result
        return `${newTitle.join(' ')} ...`;
    }
    return title;
}

const renderRecipe = recipe => {
    const markup = `
        <li>
            <a class="results__link" href="#${recipe.recipe_id}">
                <figure class="results__fig">
                    <img src="${recipe.image_url}" alt="${recipe.title}">
                </figure>
                <div class="results__data">
                    <h4 class="results__name">${limitRecipeTitle(recipe.title)}</h4>
                    <p class="results__author">${recipe.publisher}</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    `;
    elements.searchResList.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
};

// type: 'prev' or 'next'
const createButton = (page, type) => `
    <button class="btn-inline results__btn--${type}" data-goto=${type === 'prev' ? page - 1 : page + 1}>
        <span>Page ${type === 'prev' ? page - 1 : page + 1}</span>
        <svg class="search__icon">
            <use href="img/icons.svg#icon-triangle-${type === 'prev' ? 'left' : 'right'}"></use>
        </svg>
    </button>
`;

const renderButtons = (page, numResults, resPerPage) => {
    const pages = Math.ceil(numResults / resPerPage);

    let button;
    if (page === 1 && pages > 1) {
        // Only button to go to next page
        button = createButton(page, 'next');
    } else if (page < pages) {
        // Both buttons
        button = `
            ${createButton(page, 'prev')}
            ${createButton(page, 'next')}
        `;
    } else if (page === pages && pages > 1) {
        // Only button to go to prev page
        button = createButton(page, 'prev');
    }

    elements.searchResPages.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', button);
};

export const renderResults = (recipes, page = 1, resPerPage = 10) => {
    // render results of currente page
    const start = (page - 1) * resPerPage;
    const end = page * resPerPage;

    recipes.slice(start, end).forEach(recipe => renderRecipe(recipe));

    // render pagination buttons
    renderButtons(page, recipes.length, resPerPage);
};
```

The code which calls `renderResults` function is in `index.js` file. Here is that part of the code:

```
/** 
 * SEARCH CONTROLLER
 */
const controlSearch = async () => {
    // 1) Get query from view
    const query = searchView.getInput();

    if (query) {
        // 2) New search object and add to state
        state.search = new Search(query);

        // 3) Prepare UI for results
        searchView.clearInput();
        searchView.clearResults();
        renderLoader(elements.searchRes);

        try {
            // 4) Search for recipes
            await state.search.getResults();

            // 5) Render results on UI
            clearLoader();
            searchView.renderResults(state.search.result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('Something wrong with the search...');
            clearLoader();
        }
    }
}

elements.searchForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    controlSearch();
});
```

and full index.js file:

```js
import Search from './models/Search';
import Recipe from './models/Recipe';
import List from './models/List';
import Likes from './models/Likes';
import * as searchView from './views/searchView';
import * as recipeView from './views/recipeView';
import * as listView from './views/listView';
import * as likesView from './views/likesView';
import { elements, renderLoader, clearLoader } from './views/base';

/** Global state of the app
 * - Search object
 * - Current recipe object
 * - Shopping list object
 * - Liked recipes
 */
const state = {};

/** 
 * SEARCH CONTROLLER
 */
const controlSearch = async () => {
    // 1) Get query from view
    const query = searchView.getInput();

    if (query) {
        // 2) New search object and add to state
        state.search = new Search(query);

        // 3) Prepare UI for results
        searchView.clearInput();
        searchView.clearResults();
        renderLoader(elements.searchRes);

        try {
            // 4) Search for recipes
            await state.search.getResults();
    
            // 5) Render results on UI
            clearLoader();
            searchView.renderResults(state.search.result);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('Something wrong with the search...');
            clearLoader();
        }
    }
}

elements.searchForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    controlSearch();
});


elements.searchResPages.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const btn = e.target.closest('.btn-inline');
    if (btn) {
        const goToPage = parseInt(btn.dataset.goto, 10);
        searchView.clearResults();
        searchView.renderResults(state.search.result, goToPage);
    }
});


/** 
 * RECIPE CONTROLLER
 */
const controlRecipe = async () => {
    // Get ID from url
    const id = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

    if (id) {
        // Prepare UI for changes
        recipeView.clearRecipe();
        renderLoader(elements.recipe);

        // Highlight selected search item
        if (state.search) searchView.highlightSelected(id);

        // Create new recipe object
        state.recipe = new Recipe(id);

        try {
            // Get recipe data and parse ingredients
            await state.recipe.getRecipe();
            state.recipe.parseIngredients();

            // Calculate servings and time
            state.recipe.calcTime();
            state.recipe.calcServings();
    
            // Render recipe
            clearLoader();
            recipeView.renderRecipe(
                state.recipe,
                state.likes.isLiked(id)
            );

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('Error processing recipe!');
        }
    }
};
 
['hashchange', 'load'].forEach(event => window.addEventListener(event, controlRecipe));


/** 
 * LIST CONTROLLER
 */
const controlList = () => {
    // Create a new list IF there in none yet
    if (!state.list) state.list = new List();

    // Add each ingredient to the list and UI
    state.recipe.ingredients.forEach(el => {
        const item = state.list.addItem(el.count, el.unit, el.ingredient);
        listView.renderItem(item);
    });
}

// Handle delete and update list item events
elements.shopping.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const id = e.target.closest('.shopping__item').dataset.itemid;

    // Handle the delete button
    if (e.target.matches('.shopping__delete, .shopping__delete *')) {
        // Delete from state
        state.list.deleteItem(id);

        // Delete from UI
        listView.deleteItem(id);

    // Handle the count update
    } else if (e.target.matches('.shopping__count-value')) {
        const val = parseFloat(e.target.value, 10);
        state.list.updateCount(id, val);
    }
});


/** 
 * LIKE CONTROLLER
 */
const controlLike = () => {
    if (!state.likes) state.likes = new Likes();
    const currentID = state.recipe.id;

    // User has NOT yet liked current recipe
    if (!state.likes.isLiked(currentID)) {
        // Add like to the state
        const newLike = state.likes.addLike(
            currentID,
            state.recipe.title,
            state.recipe.author,
            state.recipe.img
        );
        // Toggle the like button
        likesView.toggleLikeBtn(true);

        // Add like to UI list
        likesView.renderLike(newLike);

    // User HAS liked current recipe
    } else {
        // Remove like from the state
        state.likes.deleteLike(currentID);

        // Toggle the like button
        likesView.toggleLikeBtn(false);

        // Remove like from UI list
        likesView.deleteLike(currentID);
    }
    likesView.toggleLikeMenu(state.likes.getNumLikes());
};

// Restore liked recipes on page load
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    state.likes = new Likes();
    
    // Restore likes
    state.likes.readStorage();

    // Toggle like menu button
    likesView.toggleLikeMenu(state.likes.getNumLikes());

    // Render the existing likes
    state.likes.likes.forEach(like => likesView.renderLike(like));
});


// Handling recipe button clicks
elements.recipe.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.matches('.btn-decrease, .btn-decrease *')) {
        // Decrease button is clicked
        if (state.recipe.servings > 1) {
            state.recipe.updateServings('dec');
            recipeView.updateServingsIngredients(state.recipe);
        }
    } else if (e.target.matches('.btn-increase, .btn-increase *')) {
        // Increase button is clicked
        state.recipe.updateServings('inc');
        recipeView.updateServingsIngredients(state.recipe);
    } else if (e.target.matches('.recipe__btn--add, .recipe__btn--add *')) {
        // Add ingredients to shopping list
        controlList();
    } else if (e.target.matches('.recipe__love, .recipe__love *')) {
        // Like controller
        controlLike();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like `renderResults` is being called with no arguments, or with an undefined first argument? (but the code that calls it hasn't been posted...)

Comment: just posted it above

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the same error.
After getting this error I knew about that when array or anything which you use with `slice()` undefined or null.
That's why this error happens.

```
response(dd.slice(0, 20));
```

**Error**

```
> Index:103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of
> undefined
>     at Object.success (Index:103)
>     at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
>     at done (jquery-1.12.4.js:9840)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.12.4.js:10311)
```

Comment: Yes, true. Try to do good debugging value which you use slice

Answer (score 1):

slice works on string so make sure dd is string or do dd.toString().slice(to,from);

Comment: Yea... calling .toString() on undefined will not help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error.

Its probably because your usage has reached its limit 50 calls for the day.

Wait for tomorrow or create another account  and use new key.

that worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error today, and solved it by initializing the array to an empty array before performing any slice() operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

Search the slice to find this paragraph and add a sentence:

```
if (!antDir || !antDir.length) {
  return;
}
```

To determine whether the string using the slice exists, and pages with similar situations can also be solved by this method